# bootstrap - How to display a background image on home page only?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried to display the image as a background on the homepage by giving an ID to the div and in the CSS I added this code

```
   #noorbody {


  margin: 0;
background-image: url(1.jpg);

}
```

it works but it doesn't fill the whole page. I want it to fill the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

> Rewrite your

```
    #noorbody
{
    background: url(1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **HTML** , very easy code :

```
<body background="mylocation/myimage.png">

</body>
```

Comment: mylocation is : in which directory the image exists,
myimage is : your image name,
you can also use png/jpg/etc extension